# C++ enum casting and templates

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I get the following error with VS2008: Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)

When casting a down casting a ClassA to ClassA_1 and ClassA_1 is a templated class that received an enum for parameter such as:

THIS IS AN EDIT OF MY QUESTION WHICH RE-USE AN ANSWER BELOW BUT MODIFED TO CAUSE THE PROBLEM I AM HAVING, here we go:

Ok i have been able to reproduce my error with this code:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    virtual ~ClassA(){}
};

template <class Param1 = void*> class ClassB : public ClassA {
public:
    //constructor
    ClassB(Param1 p1 = NULL)
    {
        _p1 = p1;
    }
    //ClassB(const ClassB<Param1>& ref);
    Param1 _p1;
    ~ClassB(){}
};

enum lolcakes {
    cakeisalie,
};


ClassA* ptr = new ClassB<lolcakes>(lolcakes::cakeisalie);

ClassB<lolcakes>* a1 = (ClassB<lolcakes>*)ptr;
```

Comment: Please try to post syntactically correct code in your questions.

Comment: That code won't even compile in VC10 without any instantiations of ClassA_1.

Comment: The only error I get is the non-standard extension warning for the lolcakes::cakeisalie.  Fix that and the code compiles fine on VS2010.  I have all kinds of moral objections but it does compile.

Comment: That code compiles fine for me on VS2010 too, and should do. Pointer upcasts like that are bad but not undefined or illegal. You need to post the text of the error if your compiler won't accept it.

Comment: I just tried with VS2010, and I get 2 error:
Error 1 error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'lolcakes'  
AND
Error 4 error C2548: 'ClassB<Param1>::ClassB' : missing default parameter for parameter 1

Comment: @JP - if that is what your compiler is saying then either a) your compiler is incredibly confused or, b) you are not showing us the actual code that you are compiling.  Why? Because there is no "parameter 1" in the above code.

Comment: @Konrad - no, it isn't.  NULL in C++ is 0.  NULL is specified as an "...implementation defined null pointer constant," the definition of which is, "...an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero."  NULL is simply put, not allowed to have the definition you say it does.

Comment: See Konrad Rudolph Update below. The =NULL was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many syntax errors here, I don’t know where to begin. *Next time, please post the **actual** code you used.*

For starters, I’m assuming that you meant to write this:

```
ClassA<myenum>* a = new ClassA_1<myenum>();
```

In other words, `a` is a *pointer* and its type is `ClassA<myenum>*`, not merely `ClassA` (and we’ll ignore the missing argument to the constructor).

Now, your cast syntax is wrong in both cases. The parentheses need to go around the *type only*. But better use a `static_cast` anyway:

```
ClassA_1<myenum>* a1 = static_cast<ClassA_1<myenum>*>(a);
```

This works.

**UPDATE** After question edit:

The important error is in this line:

```
ClassB(Param1 p1 = NULL)
```

you cannot use `NULL` as the default parameter since your `Param1` type is *not* a pointer – it’s an enum (strictly speaking this should work since `NULL` is defined as being equal to `0` in C++, but it’s a logical error nonetheless). Instead of making the parameter optional, a better alternative would be to overload the constructor. Alternatively, the following also works:

```
ClassB(Param1 p1 = Param1())
```

This uses the default value for the type `Param1`.

There’s an additional error in the code:

```
ClassA* ptr = new ClassB<lolcakes>(lolcakes::cakeisalie);
```

Enum constants don’t work like that in C++: They don’t create an own namespace, hence their usage cannot be qualified. Instead, omit the enum’s name:

```
ClassA* ptr = new ClassB<lolcakes>(cakeisalie);
```

Finally, please don’t use C-style casts, *ever*. Always replace them with the appropriate C++-style casts. In your case, replace

```
ClassB<lolcakes>* a1 = (ClassB<lolcakes>*)ptr;
```

with

```
ClassB<lolcakes>* a1 = boost::polymorphic_downcast<ClassB<lolcakes>*>(ptr);
// or
ClassB<lolcakes>* a1 = static_cast<ClassB<lolcakes>*>(ptr);
```

Comment: Consider using dynamic_cast or at least boost::polymorphic_downcast.

Comment: @Noah: (I scrapped my last comment.) You’re right, `boost::polymorphic_downcast` would be better. But `dynamic_cast` wouldn’t since we *know* the type of `a`. `dynamic_cast` signals “I don’t know what type the object has”, while `static_cast` signals that “I assume a type and if that assumption is wrong the this is a bug”. `dynamic_cast` should only be used if we *don’t know* for sure which type to expect, and if we subsequently check for null.

Comment: i have posted new code (in the question) which suffer from the issue.

Comment: @Konrad - I don't use those assumptions when I see those casts and I wouldn't suggest it either.  I suppose you could reword your assumption about static cast to, "This cast must be as fast as possible and if it's erroneous I am willing to allow undefined behavior to effect my customer.  I hope that it doesn't and that I've adequately made sure it won't but I know if it does that really horrible, random things could happen to the user and I've left myself no way to recover."  Not saying it doesn't have its uses but using static_cast to downcast really should be always met with that attitude.

Comment: @Noah: The operators *have* these meanings. A `dynamic_cast` definitely describes the wrong semantics here.

Comment: you got it.... =NULL is bad, it was there since my template had default time such as template <class Param1 = void*>,, but the = NULL are not needed so, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Konrad - I don't know why you think that is the case.  I could quote the standard to prove that they are not defined that way but I'd hope you realize this and can tell the difference between what you interpret them to mean when you see them and what they're actually defined to do.

Comment: @Noah: please quote away. I don’t see how my interpretation is a stretch of the definition. I respect their respective defined semantics to the letter. I reserve the right to use common sense, however. Using `dynamic_cast` when you *know* what to expect is just as stupid as checking for `null` in Java before every single method call, or double-checking whether a loop index `i` is `i >= 0 and i < N` before every subscript access. That’s called cargo-cult programming.

Comment: For the enum thing: It's a VS extension.

Comment: dynamic_cast is described in 5.2.7, static_cast is described in 5.2.9.  I think it probably better, since quoting those sections would require more than allowed here, that you simply point to those parts of the standard that define them how you've said they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassA
{
    virtual ~ClassA(){}
};

template <class Param1> class ClassB : public ClassA {
public:
    //constructor
    ClassB(Param1 p1)
        : _p1(p1) {}
    ClassB(const ClassB<Param1>& ref);
    Param1 _p1;
    ~ClassB(){}
};

enum lolcakes {
    cakeisalie,
};

ClassA* ptr = new ClassB<lolcakes>(lolcakes::cakeisalie);
ClassB<lolcakes> a = (ClassB<lolcakes>(lolcakes::cakeisalie));
ClassB<lolcakes> a1 = a;
```

Comment: i have posted new code (in the question) which suffer from the issue.